# How to make ajax call on selecting all check boxes of a jqgrid

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have jqgrid functionality implemented successfully, my intention is to make an ajax call upon selecting all check boxes of entire jqgrid.Please help.I am attaching jquery code. I am also attaching view code. screen shot of jqgrid which I got as output also I am attaching

```
$(function () {
    $("#ListGrid").jqGrid({
        url: "/TodoList/GetTodoLists",
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'Get',
        //colNames: ['<input type="checkbox" id="cbox" style="float:left" onchange="toggleCheckbox()"/>', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Id', 'Salary', 'Gender'],
        colModel: [

            { key: false, name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', editable: true },
            { key: true, hidden: true, name: 'Id', index: 'Id', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'Salary', index: 'Salary', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'Gender', index: 'Gender', editable: true }],        
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
        height: '100%',
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        caption: 'Todo List',
        emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
        jsonReader: {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            Id: "0"
        },
        autowidth: true,
        multiselect: true,        
        cellattr: function (rowId, val, rawObject) {
            return " class='cbEmpActive'";
        },
        onSelectRow: function (id, status) {
            var rowData = jQuery(this).getRowData(id);
            FirstName = rowData['FirstName'];
            LastName = rowData['LastName'];
            Salary = rowData['Salary'];
            Gender = rowData['Gender'];
            // Add this    
            alert(FirstName);
            var ch = jQuery(this).find('#' + id + ' input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked');
            if (ch) {
                jQuery(this).find('#' + id + ' input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
            }
            else {
                jQuery(this).find('#' + id + ' input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',true);
            }

            // end Add
            rowChecked = 1;
            currentrow = id;
        },
        onSelectAll: function (aSel, selected)
        {
            if (selected)
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/TodoList/Check',
                    type: 'Get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                    success: function (response)
                    {
                        var rows = response.rows;
                        var trHTML = '';
                        alert('hello');
                        $.each(rows, function ()
                        {
                            trHTML += '<tr><td>' + this.FirstName + '</td><td>' + this.LastName + '</td></tr>';
                            alert(trHTML);
                        });
                        $('#records_table').append(trHTML);
                    }
                });

            }


        }

    }).navGrid('#pager', { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: false, refresh: true },
        {
            // edit options
            zIndex: 100,
            url: '/TodoList/Edit',
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeAfterEdit: true,
            recreateForm: true,
            afterComplete: function (response) {

                if (response.responseText) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            }
        },
        {
            // add options
            zIndex: 100,
            url: "/TodoList/Create",
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeAfterAdd: true,
            afterComplete: function (response) {
                if (response.responseText) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            }
        },
        {
            // delete options
            zIndex: 100,
            url: "/TodoList/Delete",
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeAfterDelete: true,
            recreateForm: true,
            msg: "Are you sure you want to delete this task?",
            afterComplete: function (response) {
                if (response.responseText) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            }
        });
    $("#btn2").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
       // $('#ListGrid').trigger('reloadGrid');

    //$("#st1").change(function () {
      //  var value = $(this).val();
        //alert(value);

        if ($('#st1 option:selected').length > 0)
        {
            alert($('#st1 option:selected').text());
            if ($('#st1 option:selected').text() == "This is option2")
            {

                $("#ListGrid").setGridParam({ datatype: 'json', page: 1,url: "/TodoList/GridDataPrices" });
                $("#ListGrid").trigger('reloadGrid');
            }
        }



    //});
    });
    $('#btn3').click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = "/TodoList/NewAction";
        window.location.href = url;

    });
});
```

### View:-

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "TodoList";
}

<h2>TodoList</h2>
<div>
    <table id="ListGrid">

    </table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
@*<div id="div2"></div>*@
<table id="records_table" border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>LastName</th>
        @*<th>Salary</th>
        <th>Gender</th>*@
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="btn2" value="SUBMIT" />
<select id="st1">
  <option value="option1">This is option1</option>
  <option value="option2">This is option2</option>
  <option value="option3">This is option3</option>
  <option value="option4">This is option4</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="btn3" value="Next Page" />
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/TodoList.js"></script>
```

[image: Jqgrid screen shot]

Comment: Where are you facing problem?

Comment: Hi Azim, thanks for your reply.  the code written under onSelectAll is not working.

Comment: Have you tried simple `alert`? Is `alert` showing?

Comment: I tried but control is not entering into onselectall function!

Comment: This http://jsfiddle.net/HJema/256/ may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need just add `data` parameter to `$.ajax` call? You should decide yourself which format of data you prefer on the server side. The most simple would be to use

```
data: $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow").join()
```

which get the array of ids of all selected rows and converts the array to the string with comma separated ids with respect of [join](http://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_join.asp). Moreover you should verify whether `type: 'Get'` is really what you need, because could could get problems with caching of HTTP GET requests. Either you should set cache parameters in the header of HTTP response or you can just use `POST` instead of `GET`.